# C++ - Template function call operator overload - Error C2064

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading, function-call-operator

I'm trying to overload function call operator in c++ and I got this compilation error that I cannot resolve (Visual Studio 2010).

Error is in line `act(4);`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

void Test(int i);
template <class T> class Action
{
    private:
        void (*action)(T);
    public:
        Action(void (*action)(T))
        {
            this->action = action;
        }
        void Invoke(T arg)
        {
            this->action(arg);
        }
        void operator()(T arg)
        {
            this->action(arg);
        }
};

int main()
{
    Action<int> *act = new Action<int>(Test);
    act->Invoke(5);
    act(4);     //error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments overload
    char c;
    std::cin >> c;

    return 0;
}

void Test(int i)
{
    std::cout << i;
}
```

Comment: By the way, `#include <stdio.h>` is completely useless here as you never use it, and is superseded by `<iostream>` anyway.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

act is stil a pointer you have to dereference it first, like so:

```
(*act)(4);
```

Comment: Or just allocate it on the stack in the first place.

Comment: Or that, but my guess was he tried it on the stack, saw that it worked and then tried it on the heap and ran into the compilation error.